# Deploying multiple grails applications with Apache/Tomcat + Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails, deployment

I haven't been able to figure out how to deploy multiple grails applications with Apache/Tomcat where a virtual host is mapped to each grails app

I can get it so that

```
http://virtualhost1.example.com/myGrailsApplication-0.1/
```

works, but what I want is for

```
http://virtualhost1.example.com/
```

to go directly to my application. A lot of tutorial sites on the web just have you make your web app the "ROOT" one, but that won't work in a mutiple grails-app virtual host environment.

I tried using the

```
<Host name="virtualhost1.example.com" ...> </Host>
```

tags in the tomcat/conf/server.xml file, but it didn't seem to do anything (and, yes, I restarted tomcat each time I changed it.)

I also tried everything I could think of in my apache config file for the virtual host, and couldn't get it to work.

So, how can I get rid of the app name in the URL when I have multiple grails webapps, virtual hosts, and I don't want my webapp to be "ROOT"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using `mod_jk` to connect Apache & Tomcat.  If so, You will have to have to [configure virtual hosting within Tomcat as well as Apache](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) (multiple [`<Host>` declarations](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html) in your conf/server.xml)

This basically means that you'll have two `<Host ...>` declarations within conf/server.xml.  They will have different names, and appBase, but you will still have to name the war ROOT.war

The example that they gave was:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="ren">
    <Host name="ren"    appBase="renapps"/>
    <Host name="stimpy" appBase="stimpyapps"/>
</Engine>
```

After you've configured the DNS of your virtual '`<host>`s'(much like Apache) you'll have to put your ROOT.war(s) into separate folders {renapps,stimpyapps} instead of the default 'webapps' folder

This method works, but there is another method using `mod_proxy` instead of `mod_jk`.  I'm not that familiar with `mod_proxy` but basically you would have the connector handle translating the root context to the actual context. So after its configured it would proxy & forward requests sent to `http://virtualhost1.example.com/` to the right context within Tomcat (`/myGrailsApplication-0.1/`)

Let us know what you find!  Anyone else do this with `mod_proxy`?

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to give this a try as soon as I recover from my Turkey / Pie and Wine overdose...

Comment: My answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751662/how-to-deploy-multiple-grails-apps-on-one-tomcat-apache uses mod_proxy.